# Can't initialize class with "if"

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm trying to initialise a class using an `if` condition but have the following error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

I'm working on a SwiftUI project.

```
class StationCombined: Identifiable, ObservableObject {

    let information: BixiStationInformationViewModel
    let data: BixiStationDataViewModel

    init(data: BixiStationDataViewModel, information: BixiStationInformationViewModel ) {
        if data.station_id == information.station_id {
            self.data = data
            self.information = information
        }
    }

// Error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties


...

}


class StationCombinedListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var stationsCombined = [BixiStationDataViewModel]()

}
```

How should I handle the conditional statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `init`, you *must* initialize *all* properties.  In your `init`, your properties are only initialized if the `if` succeeds.

It seems you need a *failable* `init`:

```
init?(data: BixiStationDataViewModel, information: BixiStationInformationViewModel) {
    guard data.station_id == information.station_id else { return nil }
    self.data = data
    self.information = information

    ...
}
```

A *failable initializer* returns an *optional* value that is `nil` if the object couldn't be created, or a wrapped value if the `init?` succeeds.

For more info see the **Failable Initializers** section in the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html).

Comment: Thanks! It's been fixed